# Is it possible to see what files are deleted on a cluster disk in a specific directory?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, data-recovery, undelete

I need to check if there were files (accidentally deleted) in a specific directory on a clustered disk (Windows Server 2008 R2). Is there a way to do that?
The installation is relatively new and the dir was not usually used for store.